# Angular HTTP Request Works, but HttpClient Fails

Tags: angular, aws-api-gateway

I've built an API that is CORS enabled, but `HttpClient` is throwing me some weird stuff on the client-side. When I look at the Network tab in Chrome, I see the correct response to my request, but since I'm running locally, Angular is throwing a CORS error.

Here's my code:

```
public search(data: string): Promise<any> {
        const url = `${Configuration.ENDPOINTS.APP}`, headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'x-api-key': 'abcd...' });
        const body = { data: data };
        return this._http.post<any>(url, body, { headers: headers }).toPromise();
}

/// View Logic
search("test").then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Running this code, I get the following error on the Console tab of Chrome:

```
Failed to load https://abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

HttpErrorResponse
{
  "headers": {
  "normalizedNames": {},
  "lazyUpdate": null,
  "headers": {}
  },
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "Unknown Error",
  "url": null,
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
  "error": {
    "isTrusted": true
  }
}
```

However, if I look into the Network tab, this is the response:

```
Headers
    content-length: 16865
    content-type: application/json
    date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 17:34:28 GMT
    status: 200
    via: 1.1 cae81d5ff1d682b28f2deabdd94777d4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    x-amz-apigw-id: E07puFICPHcFYCA=
    x-amz-cf-id: -UYlYK_yC8cUVZF2OnRFcUb_fIjcRrgMuvpU3ADdbpyEvPZ-nUJXNA==
    x-amzn-requestid: 6d3a0533-382e-11e8-ad31-b124cb8b7a9a
    x-amzn-trace-id: sampled=0;root=1-5ac50ca4-2411d1b5cb7d1af6232883a6
    x-cache: Miss from cloudfront

Response
    {
        meta: { ... }
        data: [ ... ]
    }
```

I've omitted some things for security reasons from the response.

Does anyone know what is going on? Why does the network tab work but Angular doesn't?

**Edit:** This is part of an AWS API Gateway. All resources are CORS enabled, but for some reason the endpoints integrated with Lambda are throwing this at me. The other endpoints go straight to DynamoDB and work flawlessly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood - browser made successfully request to your API, but since request have different origin and *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header is missing - it's blocked due to security reason, which is standard behaviour of modern web browsers.

You can read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

As I see, you're using AWS API Gateway - [here is guide how to enable CORS at API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

**Edit**

If you enabled CORS, status code is 200 and still missing *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* you possibly using Lambda proxy integration at API Gateway. In that case - your Lambda is responsible for returning headers etc.

So response object should look like this:

```
{
    ...
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

[more info here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Comment: @ Michal Z. - See my updated response...all resources are CORS enabled, but it's only the ones invoking Lambda that bust.

Comment: Yeah, I see now... Anyway - if status is 200, then probably something wrong with CORS.

Comment: It's a Lambda Proxy Integration issue...if I turn proxy integration off it'll work, but I rely on the request body/params...

Comment: There is another possibility... If you using Lambda proxy integration at API Gateway - then your Lambda is responsible for return headers etc.

Comment: Hah, you write it after I clicked "Add Comment":D

Yeah, definitly that's it - check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

You need headers[''Access-Control-Allow-Origin']=...

Comment: Yup, that did it. Looking in all the wrong places today! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there are two options.
The first is to modify your backend, so that it would send localhost in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and the second (a simpler one, as for me) is to proxy your api calls. If you use angular-cli, you can configure it to proxy your requests, if not - you can use nginx - just download it, even no need to install something, and then modify the conf file (fiy)